# Android: cannot resolve method createPackageContext() error

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I am new to Android. Using Android Studio, I am creating two Application applications where I need to send a shared preference value from one application to another application. I've tried the following code:

APPLICATION-I
Java File:

```
 SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("swlpref",Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
    final String password = sharedPreferences.getString(PASSWD, "empty");
    final String rpassword = sharedPreferences.getString(RPASSWD, "empty");

            if (password.equals(rpassword)) {
                TextView textViewPass = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pass_pref_text);
                textViewPass.setText(String.valueOf(password));
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                editor.putString("swlstring", password);
                editor.commit();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Password does not match",   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

APPLICATION-II Java File:

```
power.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Context con;
            try {
                con = createPackageContext("com.gokul.security", Context.CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY);
                SharedPreferences pref = con.getSharedPreferences(
                        "swlpref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                String data = pref.getString("swlstring", "No Value");
            }

            catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
                Log.e("Not data shared", e.toString());
            }
    }
});
```

APPLICATION-I has no errors.But the problem is in Application-II, where

> cannot resolve method createPackageContext()

error is shown.

I've also imported android.content.Context package.

Still I could not solve this error. I've been trying for several hours but unhelpful.

Help Please. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Shared preferences are private to the app by default. Why dont you try creating a db in sdcard?

Just saw that you have defined Mode_private which will not allow them to be shared among packages

Comment: I am just creating this application for sample reference. I thought it would be easy with shared preference. These applications are for my very own purposes. Thanks for reply , but it would be grateful if I get an answer for my question.

Comment: Yes, but that mode is private for second application alone. I am not going to share it globally to other applications. But my mode is global for first application, so that my second app can get access to it.. And also I specified that the problem is with the method. The method is itself not available, though importing my Context package.

Comment: Inside on click the context is of the button. Try to get context of your activity and then ActivityContext.createPackageContext

Comment: As I am new to android, I cannot understand , though I could understand a little bit.. Can you please show me how the code should be?.. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Try getApplicationContext.createPackageContext("com.gokul.security", Context.CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY);
                SharedPreferences pref = con.getSharedPreferences(
                        "swlpref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                String data = pref.getString("swlstring", "No Value");

Comment: getApplicationContext()

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.
I created a new java activity file. And paste those codes of Application-II in that activity. Using "Intent" from Application-II I was able to solve this problem.

```
power.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(),
                    Check.class);
            startActivityForResult(i, 0);
```

"Check.java" is my new java activity. Paste those shared preferences statements there and createPackageContext() method shown no error.

Thanks Kay for Your Help :)